# php - global variables "concatenation"?

Tags: php

My friend let me look at his source code, and I just got around to it. I would ask him, but he's in vacation at switzerland.

```
$path = $_SESSION['a']['b'][$_GET['c']];
```

What exactly does that mean? Does it just concatenate those? 
If I sent in `Cookie:a=/a/&b=b/` along with `?c=test.php` , would the `$path` var be `/a/b/test.php`? If not, what would it be equal to?

Comment: If you're interested in what it would look like, why don't you run the code?

Comment: Look up [arrays and subscripts](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). This is extracting a value from a nested array.

Comment: `print_r($_SESSION);` and `echo $_GET['c'];` and see if you can work it out.

Comment: `$_SESSION` is an array, the element with key `a` is accessed, then the element with the key `b` is accessed within `a`, finally the `$_GET` value of `c` is used to access an element of array `b`. ;)

Comment: They're just using the value of `$_GET['c']` as a key for their array. Nothing really technical or fancy going on here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SESSION['a']['b'][$_GET['c']]` means a series of steps like the following steps:

```
$x_ = $_SESSION;
$x_2 = $x_['a'];
$x_3 = $x_2['b'];
$v = $_GET['c'];
$x_4 = $x_3[$v];
```

and you get and keep $x_4.

Long explanation: get a value under index 'a' from the session array, then get a sub value from that value (which is an array) under the index 'b', and so on.

Comment: oh, I can see what's happening. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION['a']['b'][$_GET['c']];
```

means that you are accessing a session variable named 'a'.

Where 'a' is assumed as a multidimensional array, assumed to have a key 'b' where it is also an array, an array assumed to have a key equal to whatever the value of $_GET['c'].

Let's assumed that $_GET['c'] is equal to 'c',
so the assumed structure of your array would be:

```
$_SESSION['a'] = array(
    'b' => array(
         'c' => "This is the value you are trying to fetch."
    )
);
```